# How to not scrape the same url twice?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xampp, python-requests, export-to-csv

My over all goal is to have an array/list of urls that don't get scraped during a website url scrape the logic as seem in the code sample below is

logic for ('scrapy.py'):

open url in ('source') ~> find 'a' tags from url in ('source') ~> find 'href' in 'a' tags ~> if value of 'href' is not equal to(!=) ('done') in file ('doneurls.py') ~> then write urls that aren't equal to ('done') into file ('url.py')

The code i'm using is 'scrapy.py':

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import os
import sys
from os.path import dirname, join, abspath
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '..')))
from doneurls import done


source = requests.get('http://localhost/index.php').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
file = open('./url.py', 'a')
csv_writer = csv.writer(file)

 from html.parser import HTMLParser

 class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        # Only parse the 'anchor' tag.
        if tag == "a":
           # Check the list of defined attributes.
             for name, value in attrs:
           # If href is defined, print it.
           if name == "href":
            if value != done:
                csv_writer.writerow('b="'+value+'"')



parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(source)
file.close()
```

index.php:

```
<a href="http://localhost/next.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/next3.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/next2.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/next1.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/1.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/2.php">hello</a>
<a href="http://localhost/3.php">hello</a>
```

doneurls.py:

```
done = "http://localhost/2.php"
```

This code seems to work and it ignores only one url that I add to doneurls.py and works well, but what i'm looking to do is to add an array of urls to done like this

```
done = {
"http://localhost/2.php",
"http://localhost/next1.php",
"http://localhost/next2.php"}
```

When I try to run 'done' as an array no urls are skipped over at all. I'm using this code to try to not have to scrape urls that I've scraped in the past.

Comment: Please provide a description to your problem that's something other than code and format your code.

Comment: the question was in the process of being changed. Maybe the new information with provide more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem well, you are trying to see if each URL found has been done already or not, using:

```
if value != done:
```

Except the problem is that the above allows the check for only one `done` url instead of the potentially multiple urls already done. So, if `done` becomes a list, you can use the operator [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) (here you will need `not in` because we want to check if it's not there):

```
if value not in done:
```

---

As a side note, lists in Python are created using square brackets, so, `done` will be should similar to something like this:

```
done = [
    "http://localhost/2.php",
    "http://localhost/next1.php",
    "http://localhost/next2.php"
]
```

Braces are for [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s and [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), although making `done` a set doesn't matter too much here.